# How to define a `\citejournal` command in amsrefs

Tags: citing, journal, amsrefs

I know that there are `\citeauthor{BibKey}` and `\citeyear{BibKey}` in `amsrefs`, is anyone can help me define a newcommand that print the `JOURNAL` field in BibTeX item?

The MME:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[abbrev, alphabetic]{amsrefs}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article {BHGE2017Bayesian,
    AUTHOR = {B\"{o}hm, Vanessa and Hilbert, Stefan and Greiner, Maksim and
              En\ss lin, Torsten A.},
     TITLE = {Bayesian weak lensing tomography: reconstructing the 3{D}
              large-scale distribution of matter with a lognormal prior},
   JOURNAL = {Phys. Rev. D},
  FJOURNAL = {Physical Review D},
     LABEL = {B\"{o}hm, 2017, Phys. Rev. D},
    VOLUME = {96},
      YEAR = {2017},
    NUMBER = {12},
     PAGES = {123510, 19},
      ISSN = {2470-0010},
   MRCLASS = {85A35 (83B05)},
  MRNUMBER = {3870877},
       DOI = {10.1103/physrevd.96.123510},
       URL = {https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevd.96.123510},
}
\end{filecontents}
\makeatletter\catcode`'=11
\DeclareRobustCommand{\jcite}[1]{%
  (\citeauthor{#1}, \citeyear{#1}, \star@{\cite@a\citesel@journal{#1}}{})%
}
%\makeatother\catcode`'=12
\begin{document}
The citation should looks like \texttt{(B\"ohm et. al, 2017, Phys. Rev, D., Thm.~3)} for the citation \cite{BHGE2017Bayesian}*{Thm.~3}.

%\jcite{BHGE2017Bayesian}
\bibliography{\jobname}

%\begin{bibdiv}
%\begin{biblist}
%
%\bib{BHGE2017Bayesian}{article}{
%      author={B\"{o}hm, Vanessa},
%      author={Hilbert, Stefan},
%      author={Greiner, Maksim},
%      author={En\ss~lin, Torsten~A.},
%       title={Bayesian weak lensing tomography: reconstructing the 3{D}
%  large-scale distribution of matter with a lognormal prior},
%        date={2017},
%        ISSN={2470-0010},
%     journal={Phys. Rev. D},
%      volume={96},
%      number={12},
%       pages={123510, 19},
%         url={https://doi.org/10.1103/physrevd.96.123510},
%      review={\MR{3870877}},
%}
%
%\end{biblist}
%\end{bibdiv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The cheap solution would be https://ctan.org/pkg/usebib. But I don't know if `amsrefs` might have a built-in way to deal with this, since their internal format is structured LaTeX-readable data.